# 12.10 shutdown not working

Tags: 12.10, kernel, shutdown

I hope i don't sound like a noob, but my shutdown isn't working. I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 and whenever I shut down and press`ESC` to see what's happening, it isn't doing anything. When I return to look at the dots, they are doing what they normally do (whether you consider it changing colors or moving or whatever), but shutdown isn't progressing. I tried downgrading my kernel to 3.5.0-26 but to no avail. Is there anything I can do to fix this (preferably not a fresh installation) because I don't want to have to force shutdown. I know it's not the best for your hard drive, but does it have the same side effects for an SSD.

If anyone has any suggestions, PLEASE tell me.

Comment: I had some of these problems, but after updating or upgrading ubuntu it got solved..it was a bug i think

Answer (score 0):

Better perform a `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`